# How can I emit values by my own method in RXJava 2?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, callable

Well, I would like to use RXJava2 Observable to emit data until I get an exception in my method. How can I do it?

This piece of code runs once and emits 100.

```
Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return 100;
    }
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(result -> outTextView.setText(result));
```

And I would like to execute the code below and emit the result until I get an exception.

```
new ObdResetCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
new EchoOffCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
new LineFeedOffCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
new SelectProtocolCommand(ObdProtocols.AUTO).run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());

ResetTroubleCodesCommand clear = new ResetTroubleCodesCommand();
clear.run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
String result = clear.getFormattedResult();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post your pice of code and ask for a specific question

Comment: Can you give a little more of context about this? I'm trying really hard to imagine what you are trying to do but I cannot guess.

Comment: Do you want to emit multiple results? See `Observable.create` and `emitter.onNext` with it.

Comment: It's about live data. I would like to create a background service with RXJava2 to send requests, get data continuously and update the UI with the results. I would like to send 5 requests every second or two seconds, and show the result to the user. That's all I want.

Comment: Thank you very much, akarnokd! Thats what I'm looking for!